# Why is my parser generating reporting that this LALR(1) grammar is not LALR(1)?

Tags: parsing, lalr

OK, my adventures with my parser generator continued. This time I got my hands on a classic grammar, which is said to be a LALR grammar:

```
start -> a a
a -> "A" a
a -> "B"
```

When I put it into my parser generator it gives me that output:

```
LIST OF STATES:
-----------------------
<0: S' -> . start , $
start -> . a a , $
a -> . "A" a , "A" / "B"
a -> . "B" , "A" / "B"
{NTerm(start): 1, Term(A): 2, Term(B): 3, NTerm(a): 4}>(3104365621624877555)

--------------------
<1: S' -> start .  , $
{}>(3969511602615904846)

--------------------
<2: a -> "A" . a , "A" / "B"
a -> . "A" a , "A" / "B"
a -> . "B" , "A" / "B"
{Term(A): 2, Term(B): 3, NTerm(a): 5}>(5490562805113673592)

--------------------
<3: a -> "B" .  , "A" / "B"
{}>(-4845209343945471034)

--------------------
<4: start -> a . a , $
a -> . "A" a , $
a -> . "B" , $
{Term(A): 6, Term(B): 7, NTerm(a): 8}>(598157158659875896)

--------------------
<5: a -> "A" a .  , "A" / "B"
{}>(436327415052220213)

--------------------
<6: a -> "A" . a , $
a -> . "A" a , $
a -> . "B" , $
{Term(A): 6, Term(B): 7, NTerm(a): 9}>(5490562805113673592)

--------------------
<7: a -> "B" .  , $
{}>(-4845209343945471034)

--------------------
<8: start -> a a .  , $
{}>(5795088700656730485)

--------------------
<9: a -> "A" a .  , $
{}>(436327415052220213)

POSSIBLE STATES TO JOIN: (2, 6), (3, 7), (5, 9)
ATTEMPTING CONVERSION TO LALR GRAMMAR...FAILED
CONTINUING WITH CLR(1)...
```

These states match what I can read in other sources about compiling LALR grammars — this step looks OK, it produces correct states like if I had done it by hand. The generator suggest — again it is what other sources say about conversing CLR(1) grammar into LALR — that states `(2,6)`,`(3,7)`,`(5,9)` can be joined, but it is unable to do so.
When I look at produced *action* and *goto* tables I can see why:

[image: Resulting action and goto table]

As you can see states 2 and 6 can't be joined, because there are incompatible items `s2 <> s6`, `s3 <> s7` and so on.

But what amazes me the most is the generator finished its work and produced a running program. When I run this program on test data, it accepts the data! So, my generator produced the correct tables.

Does it mean this classic "LALR" grammar is LALR only when a human does the compilation by hand?  What my parser generator does differently?

Comment: "is said to be" and "read in other sources" carefully fail to specify the actual source of the information. If you suspect that the advice you are getting is incorrect, it's best to actually cite the source or, if possible, provide a link. Also, wrt the output from your grammar generator, what value is being contributed by those enormous apparently arbitrary numbers? If they are pointers, consider using a hexadecimal output format: in C, at least, you have the `%p` format for `void*`.

Comment: Your generator is LR(1) -- and since LR(1) is a superset of LALR(1) it can handle an LALR(1) grammar just fine, it just ends up with extra states.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the issue is here:

> As you can see states 2 and 6 can't be joined, because there are incompatible items s2 <> s6, s3 <> s7 and so on.

That's actually not quite right. Notice that in state 2, the shift items take you to, respectively, states 2 and 3. In state 6, the shift items take you to, respectively, states 6 and 7. But there's no incompatibility there, because you're attempting to merge states 2 and 6 together and to merge states 3 and 7 together. In other words, yes, those shifts do *currently* say to go to different places, but after you collapse all states with the same core together, you'll end up with them all saying to go to the same place.

More generally, I don't believe there's any case where merging two LR(1) states will introduce a "shift/shift" conflict. To see why this is, note that each LR(1) state corresponds to a state in an LR(0) parser, except that each LR item has been annotated with a set of lookahead items. In going from LR(1) to LALR(1), you're combining together LR(1) states with the same items ignoring lookaheads, meaning that you're essentially combining together LR(1) states that correspond to the same LR(0) state.

As a result, if you have an LR(1) state S that says "go to state T on symbol a", then the LR(0) state corresponding to S has a transition to the LR(0) state corresponding to T, and that's also going to be true for any LR(1) state that S is going to be merged with.

The only conflicts that can arise in the course of building an LALR(1) parser are reduce/reduce conflicts, which is what you need to be on guard for.

Comment: Dragon book sec 4.7, p. 237 (in first edition, I believe): "Thus, the merging of states with common cores can never produce a shift/reduce conflict that was not present in one of the original states, because shift actions depend only on the core, not the lookahead."

Comment: Things like this make me facepalm and asking to myself "What were you thinking?". Yeah, I forgot to take into consideration the fact those conflicting shift operations are going to be the same operations _after_ the join. Silly me...

Answer (score 1):

I don't know what your parser generator does, but standard parser generators have no trouble with that grammar. Here, for example, is bison's state transition table, generated with:

```
bison --report-file=aa.output --report=all --graph=aa.dot --output=/dev/null \
      <(printf "%%%%\n%s" "start: a a; a: 'A' a | 'B'")
dot -o aa.png -Tpng aa.dot
```

(Bison is a really handy tool; even if you're writing your own parser generator, you can take advantage of its capabilities. See also its XML output.)
[image]

And here's the slightly edited report file (I removed the list of terminals and non-terminals, and some blank lines, so as to use up less space.)

```
Grammar

    0 $accept: start $end
    1 start: a a
    2 a: 'A' a
    3  | 'B'

State 0
    0 $accept: . start $end
    1 start: . a a
    2 a: . 'A' a
    3  | . 'B'

    'A'  shift, and go to state 1
    'B'  shift, and go to state 2

    start  go to state 3
    a      go to state 4

State 1
    2 a: . 'A' a
    2  | 'A' . a
    3  | . 'B'

    'A'  shift, and go to state 1
    'B'  shift, and go to state 2

    a  go to state 5

State 2
    3 a: 'B' .

    $default  reduce using rule 3 (a)

State 3
    0 $accept: start . $end

    $end  shift, and go to state 6

State 4
    1 start: a . a
    2 a: . 'A' a
    3  | . 'B'

    'A'  shift, and go to state 1
    'B'  shift, and go to state 2

    a  go to state 7

State 5
    2 a: 'A' a .

    $default  reduce using rule 2 (a)

State 6
    0 $accept: start $end .

    $default  accept

State 7
    1 start: a a .

    $default  reduce using rule 1 (start)
```